# UIKeyboard issue in UITextfield and UITextview

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I couldn’t able to enter space character in UITextview or UITextfield while tapping space from UIKeyboard. After multiple taps, a single space character will appear in UITextview.
Do you have any solution for this issue?

Comment: Are you using *UITextViewDelegate* or *UITexfieldDelegate*?

Comment: Currently we are using textviewdelegate

Comment: Share your code of TextViewDelegate. It will be easy to figure out your problem.

Comment: share your code please in order to help

Answer (score 0):

I used to the same problem. Maybe it's a bug of Apple if you use added font. Let's try with System font. It works for me